# Init Laravel passport from within docker

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-passport

I'm in the process of dockerizing our dev environement. The application consists among other things of a laravel app exposing a REST API. Authentication is done through laravel passport.

As this is intented for dev only, I'm installing composer dependencies, setting application encryption key, migrating datatabases and setting passport keys at run time. Everything is initialised correctly except for the passport keys. No matter how I tried to approach the problem I end up with the following error:

> fpm_1    | In CryptKey.php line 45:
>
> fpm_1    |
>
> fpm_1    |   Key path "file:///var/www/html/storage/oauth-public.key" does not exist or
>
> fpm_1    |   is not readable

This is the relevant part of my docker-compose file.

```
version: '3'
  services:
  fpm:
      build: ./api/docker/fpm
      restart: unless-stopped
      volumes:
        - ./api:/var/www/html
        - /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd
      user: "${UID}:${GID}"
```

My fpm dockerfile (./api/docker/fpm/Dockerfile)

```
FROM php:7.2.6-fpm
COPY ./init-app.sh /usr/local/bin/
COPY ./install-composer.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libfreetype6-dev \
libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
libmcrypt-dev libpng-dev \
libzip-dev \
libzip4 \
git \
zip \
wget \
&& apt-get autoremove \
&& apt-get clean \
&& docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
&& docker-php-ext-install gd \
&& docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-libzip=/usr/include/ \
&& docker-php-ext-install zip \
&& docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
&& chmod +x /usr/local/bin/init-app.sh \
&& chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-composer.sh \
&& /usr/local/bin/install-composer.sh \
&& rm /usr/local/bin/install-composer.sh \
&& wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/8ed92e8cab83cfed76ff012ed4a36cef74b28096/wait-for-it.sh \
&& chmod +x wait-for-it.sh \
&& mv wait-for-it.sh /usr/local/bin/
ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/local/bin/init-app.sh" ]
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

install-composer.sh installs composer into the container at build time.

init-app.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
# Install composer dependencies
composer install

# Copy env file
cp .env.example .env

# Wait for DB to be up
/usr/local/bin/wait-for-it.sh db:3306 -t 0 --strict -- php artisan key:generate && php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
php artisan passport:install

# Run upstream entrypoint

# first arg is `-f` or `--some-option`
if [ "${1#-}" != "$1" ]; then
    set -- php-fpm "$@"
fi

exec "$@"
```

My user is correctly mapped inside the fpm container as I export $UID and $GID in .zshrc. Commenting out the passport:install line in my init-app.sh in order to let container boot correctly, I'm able to generate the keys by running docker exec -it php artisan passport:install just fine. But letting the container handle it fails.

Comment: missing `&&` before `php artisan passport:install`, and in many places :)

Comment: @Hussein the artisan passport:install command is on a new line

Comment: yep silly me :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, one of my database seeder, somehow required the key to be present. while I investigate, I fixed the problem by swapping instructions (the seeding and passport keys installation)